# Google Play : what are the countries in "Rest of the World"?

Tags: google-play, countries

we have some problems to distribute our app on some islands, we need to enable our app to be available in "Rest of the World".

But we need to know exactly where the app will be available for our users.

I did not find the list of countries/locations that are define in "Rest of the World".

Does someone has this list ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the list from Google.

1. Afghanistan
2. Andorra
3. Anguilla
4. Antarctica
5. Barbados
6. Bhutan
7. Bouvet Island
8. British Indian Ocean Territory
9. Brunei Darussalam
10. Burundi
11. Central African Republic
12. Christmas Island
13. Cocos (Keeling) Islands
14. Cook Islands
15. Curaçao
16. Equatorial Guinea
17. Eswatini (formerly Swaziland)
18. Ethiopia
19. Falkland Islands (Malvinas)
20. French Southern Territories
21. Georgia
22. Guernsey
23. Guyana
24. Heard and Mcdonald Islands
25. Isle of Man
26. Jersey
27. Kiribati
28. Kosovo
29. Lesotho
30. Madagascar
31. Malawi
32. Mauritania
33. Mongolia
34. Montenegro
35. Montserrat
36. Nauru
37. Niue
38. Norfolk Island
39. Palestinian Territory
40. Pitcairn
41. Saba
42. Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha
43. Saint Vincent and Grenadines
44. Sao Tome and Principe
45. South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands
46. Timor-Leste
47. Tokelau
48. Tuvalu
49. US Minor Outlying Islands
50. Western Sahara

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12201481

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble finding out what is included in "Rest of the World".

Answer (score 1):

The exact list is not published by Google Play right now and changes with geo-political changes in the world, but you should treat it as if it is all countries in the rest of the world.

Answer (score -1):

Rest of the World means; countries not listed for some reason or not included.

Comment: This does not answer to what the OP is asking.